# Workaround for race condition with background job

Tags: ruby-on-rails, resque, race-condition

I'm working on a `Rails 3.0.19` app (`ruby 1.9.2`), using `MySQL 5.1`. Abstracting a bit from the actual code, what I've got is something like this:

`Widgets` and their `Parts` have `name` attributes, and the names of the `Parts` is sometimes derived from the name of the associated `Widget`. So naturally when a `Widget`'s name is updated, I want to also update the names of the `Parts`. This can take a reasonable amount of time (~60s), so I want to do it in a background job. Thus:

```
class Widget < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :parts

  after_save :update_part_names

  def update_part_names
    if name_was && name_changed?
      Resque.enqueue Widget, { 'widget' => self.id, 'old_name' => name_was }
    end
  end

  def self.perform(args)
    widget = Widget.find(args['widget'])
    widget.parts.each do |part|
      new_name = part.name.sub(args['old_name'], widget.name)
      part.name = new_name
      part.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Now, in my development environment this works great. But then I push this code to our staging environment in which we have many resque workers running on a separate box from the app server. Now the update gets queued up, and appears to complete successfully, but the actual update happens on some `Widget.name` updates and not others. If I run `Widget.perform` from the console, it works 100% of the time.

My hypothesis was that this was a race condition -- in the staging environment with more things happening in parallel, the job was being queued up and then executing before the `save` transaction for the `Widget` was completed (this can take a second; `Widgets` are complicated objects with many associations). Thus, `Widget.find` in the resque job was loading a `Widget` record that still had the old name, so `part.name.sub(args['old_name'], self.name)` was doing nothing.

I tried adding the following code to the method for the job:

```
def self.perform(args)
  widget = Widget.find(args['widget'])
  if widget.name == args['old_name']
    Resque.enqueue Widget, args
  else
    # run as before
```

The thought was that this would just keep re-queueing the job as long as the update to the `Widget` name hadn't yet been committed, and then it would succeed. But I'm still seeing the  behavior where the `part` names get updated sometimes, but not always. (And as far as I can tell, the job is never being queued more than once per update.)

So two questions: (1) is my diagnosis of the problem wrong to begin with? (2) how do I get my update job to run successfully every time?

Edit: increasingly sure that this really is a race condition; adding `sleep 60` to the background job prior to `Widget.find` seems to make the update happen successfully 100% of the time. But I don't regard that as an acceptable solution.

Comment: just couple of thing though `a )` does the name always change when you do a update if not the after_save would be called everytime regardless that very expensive as you said you have large complex record perhaps a conditional callback would make sense there  ; `b )` Is your code correct as in what is `self.name` doing then inside a class method doing anyway it as good as `Widget.name` and I dont thing you need that correct you need `widget.name` so the condition ` if self.name == args['old_name']` would sum up like this "Widget" == args['old_name'] Please check that :)

Comment: You're right, but that error isn't in the actual code, it was just an error with transcription to stack overflow. In the actual code we use `self.perform` to fetch the `Widget` instance and call a method on the instance. I tried to alter the code for this post since that extra indirection is beside the point, but I just missed that reference to `self`. Fixed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution with the help of http://logicalfriday.com/2012/08/21/rails-callbacks-workers-and-the-race-you-never-expected-to-lose/

I had previously considered using an `after_commit` callback rather than `after_save`, but had rejected that idea on the grounds that in `after_commit` we no longer have access to `name_was`. However, apparently Rails makes changes available even after they've been committed (though `reload`ing the object from the database will discard them), via the `previous_changes` hash. E.g.,

```
after_commit :update_part_names

def update_part_names
  return unless self.previous_changes['name'].try(:first)
  Resque.enqueue Widget,
    { 'widget' => self.id, 'old_name' => self.previous_changes['name'].first }
end
```

`previous_changes` looks like:

```
{ "name" => ['old_name', 'updated_name'] }
```

Comment: Great you find it but I still feel I would worked with after_save just check though since self.name in self.perform would always be "Widget"

Comment: oh, that's just a mistake with the transcription to stackoverflow; the actual method our actual job ends up using is an instance method (there's an extra level of indirection that I tried to abstract away from for my post, since it was beside the point).

Answer (score 0):

Some thoughts - you could do a few things to minimize the chance of a race condition.  First - enqueue jobs for parts, not the widget.  A failure will only affect the part that failed.  Then, when you are processing the jobs, do an update_column instead of a save! - it'll go a lot faster and you won't trigger other callbacks.

```
class Part

  belongs_to :widget

  def self.perform(args)
    part = Part.find(args['part'])
    part.update_column(:name, part.name.sub(args['old_name'], self.name))
  end

end
```

It would also be nice if you didn't have to send in the old name, can you simply recreate the part name using an existing method?

Comment: While these are some good suggestions, I don't see that they'll help with the race condition. It doesn't matter how fast the part name update is (although if we could make it fast enough we wouldn't need to do it in a background job at all). It's saving the widget that's slow, and it's the fact that it's slow that potentially triggers the race condition.

Also, `update_column` isn't available in Rails 3.0. (But that's not that big a deal, I could achieve the same effect if I cared to.)

Comment: @Swards One thing self.name inside class method `perform`